# Perl script are not running on Apache 2.2.15 with mod_fcgid / Win32

Tags: windows, perl, apache

I have installed apache 2.2.15 with mod_fcgid on Windows XP SP3 and Activestate Perl (tried both 5.12 & 5.8.9)
tried the perl example script in the mod_fcgid reference page but it 
is not working

I get this in error log

[Tue Dec 07 23:10:35 2010] [info] mod_fcgid: server 127.0.0.1:/usr/bin/perl.exe(5476) started
[Tue Dec 07 23:10:35 2010] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : mod_fcgid  : get overlap result error
[Tue Dec 07 23:10:35 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: f.pl
[Tue Dec 07 23:10:35 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 07 23:10:39 2010] [info] mod_fcgid - infoneto: process /usr/bin/perl.exe(5476) exit(communication error), return code 9

I double check everything including: 
The #!/usr/bin/perl.exe line 
The mod_fcgid is loaded

When running the script as plain cgi it works 
When I turned to the older mod_fastcgi it works just fine as a fastcgi (i.e. loads once runs many times).

Using process monitor I can see that apache starts Perl but it Perl exits almost instantly without even loading the Perl script 
I tried it also on Apache 2.0.52 & 2.0.63 with older mod_fcgid and with Apache 2.2.15 with the newest mod_fcgid (2.3.6) but no luck

What can be done ?

I googled around but no one seems to have solution or managed using mod_fcgid with perl on Win32

I opened a bug on both FCGI at cpan and on apache tracker but no one seems to care...

Is there a solution for this ? 
Does someone else need this ? (mod_fcgid with Perl on Apache/Win32)

Answer (score 2):

You're on Win32, and you *have* a `/usr/bin/perl.exe`? Are you sure?

Regardless, I think you're looking for `mod_fastcgi` rather than `mod_fcgid`; at least, a quick google search seemed that it fixed the problem for most. Apparently `mod_fcgid` is not working as well under Windows.

Comment: I use /usr/bin/perl so my scripts run on both my FreeBSD and Windows machines without any change. Regarding mod_fastcgi - mod_fcgid is actively developed and replaced mod_fastcgi in apache as the first choice (it is actually part of apache projects). I did my homework searching the web but as I did not found an answer I asked my question here...

Comment: This problem is not solved yet. from what I have checked it is somehow relates to the way Windows behaves with STDERR SDTOUT etc...