# Persistent, preforked (blocking) Perl web service on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, fastcgi, psgi

I would like to run a Perl web application on Windows (assume 2008 R2 x64) with reasonable speed / capacity.

Currently my app is based on Mojolicious, using Strawberry Perl and running as CGI through Apache 2.2-win32. With about 20000 lines of code, the creation of the perl process takes a lot of time, almost a second or two while the actually processing is just a blink of a second.
I would imagine it to be running much faster and be able to serve much more req/sec if the app is configured in a Fast CGI or persistent style.

If I am on Linux, I would probably have sticked with the PSGI/Plack/Starman and Nginx reverse proxying.
Unfortunately, Starman/Starlet does not support Win32.

Morbo/Twiggy does not meet my need because the webapp does block (DB calls) and for some request it does take a while to finish.

So I am looking at Fast CGI solution right now. Unfortunately Apache and mod_fcgid does not work with Perl ([Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382661/perl-script-are-not-running-on-apache-2-2-15-with-mod-fcgid-win32)). And I am yet be able to found or work out a compatible binary with mod_fastcgi with 2.4.  Something I didn't try yet is mod_fastcgi + Apache 2.2, but I wish I could stay on Apache 2.4.

I am also thinking if I could run my own FCGI process manager (the thing that manage preforking), together with Mojo::Server::FastCGI, and use mod_proxy_fcgi to do reverse proxy instead. Perl module FCGI::ProcManager also does not support Win32. Could there be any other process manager, prehaps in C#? (Preferably in C# for further hacking)

Let me sum up the question -

- What's the best way to run Perl web app on Windows at a speed much faster than CGI, but not in non-blocking style.
- and prehaps that lead to a question of - how to make mod_fcgid works with Perl? Or is there any fcgi process manager out there?

Comment: mod_perl has been preferable to CGI for over a decade.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a `fork` call, so real `preforked` is impossible on Windows.

Comment: mod_perl may save the cost of creating the perl process, but might not save the cost of re-compiling my codes again.  And I am expecting the code to grow.

Comment: There might not be fork(), but definitely have some alternatives that does similar thing. I agree that might not be easy to code in Perl though.

Comment: On the other hand, I wonder why no one made a pure perl PSGI Server with threads instead of fork? I might go ahead and write one, but is there any pitfall I might have not foreseen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the threaded Plack server [Thrall](http://blogs.perl.org/users/piotr_roszatycki/2013/07/plack-server-with-threads-1.html).

Comment: I ended up implementing something very some time ago but never get polished to publish. It requires some hack on Net::Server, here and there. Finally someone got the time to do it, and I hope it is done right =).  I would love to try that out when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

you could use Mojolicious + mod_psgi + apache.

There are pre-compiled binaries here, although for Apache 2.2:

http://strawberryperl.com/package/kmx/mod_psgi/

--
Mike